# Dynamic filtering based on 2 parameters, one being an empty cell

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, filtering

I am trying to create a fairly simple excel based In and Out log. I have a user form, to check someone in, and a user form to check someone out. When checked in, there is a new entry(row) added to the data tab, with name, time in, etc... there is also a "time out" column that is left blank. Then when they are checked out the column "time out" is populated.

I want to be able to show a current log of everyone in the facility(on a tab separate from the data). By filtering based on all entries that have a "time in" but do not currently have a value for "time out". What would be the best way to handle this? I have tried an advanced filter, but cant seem to get it to check for the right variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the =COUNTA() formula, which counts how many cells have anything in them in the following manner. If you have a column for each of name, time in, and time out, you could add a fourth column called "In the building" which would have the formula `=IF(COUNTA(A3:C3)=3,"yes","no")`
You can then filter this column to get all of the "yes" people.

Comment: This is working, thank you for your help, I would have never thought to handle it this way.